# Создать массив и удалить повторяющиеся значения

Tags: javascript, массивы

Например:

```
let a = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150];
```

Тут повторяются два числа, нужно удалить повторяющиеся числа.
Как это сделать?

Comment: пройдите циклом по всему массиву и в условии пропишите, что если есть схожее значение оно должно быть удалено

Comment: Перегоните массив в коллекцию, где значение массива будет ключом. Дубликаты сами удалятся...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 способ:

```js
function unique(arr) {
  let result = [];

  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    let currentItem = item;
    let wasAdded = false;
    result.forEach(function (itemInResult) {
      if (itemInResult == currentItem) {
        wasAdded = true;
        return;
      }
    });
    if (!wasAdded) result.push(currentItem);
  });
  
  return result;
}

let a = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150];

alert(unique(a));
```

2 способ:

```js
function unique(arr) {
  let result = [];

  nextInput:
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let str = arr[i]; // для каждого элемента
      for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) { // ищем, был ли он уже?
        if (result[j] == str) continue nextInput; // если да, то следующий
      }
      result.push(str);
    }

  return result;
}

let a = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150];

alert(unique(a));
```

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/array-unique)

Comment: Добавьте, если можете, ещё вариант с `forEach()`, чтоб нагляднее было. Добавил вам +1

Comment: @Карен Оганнисян примите ответ, вам тут все наглядно расписали (это элементарная вежливость на SO, автор ответа старался и вложил свое время в ответ вам). Принять можно нажав галочку под голосами.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Да знаю просто там 7 минут еще не прошло а то я принял бы)

Comment: @КаренОганнисян хорошее начало, ждем от вас хороших вопросов и ответов.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    const arr = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150];  
    const result = arr.filter( (item, pos) => {
        return arr.indexOf(item) === pos;
    })
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: const это что? можно объяснение?

Answer (score 0):

Самый короткий вариант:

```js
let a = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150]; 
a = Array.from(new Set(a)); 

document.body.textContent = a.join(', ');
```

Сначала создаем `Set` из элементов массива, а затем преобразуем обратно в массив, используя статический метод `Array.from()`.

---

Это медленный способ, но для небольших массивов он вполне применим.
С огромными массивами - в плане скорости, нет ничего лучше обычного перебора в `for` или `while`.
А универсальный "средний" вариант - перебирающие методы класса `Array`: компактно, удобно, без лишних затрат времени и памяти.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this way ==>

```
function unique( arr ) {
    let rsp = [];
    for (let part; arr.length && ( part = arr.shift() ); ) {
        rsp.indexOf(part) > -1 ? undefined : rsp.push(part);
    }
    return rsp;
};
let a = [10, 20, 60, 10, 40, 150, 150];
let b = unique(xo);
console.log(b);
```